# Magento 2 How to add custom validation rules and apply them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, magento2

I'm trying to modify some validation rules for the State input in shipping address. I want to add an error message if user selects 'Texas'.

I created a mixin for `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules` in `requirejs-config.js`

I can add a new rule called 'customTexasValidationRule' in the rules collection. However i don't know how to apply this rule to the select input.

I see that i can declare the rules in the select template at `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/select.html` but i don't want to create a new template file for such a small task.

Is there any quick and easy way to add such a small custom validation in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to accomplish this:

I added a mixin for `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator`:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function($) {
    return function(validator) {
        validator.addRule(
            'custom-rule',
            function (value) {
                // Custom rule logics here
                return false;
            $.mage.__('Custom error message')
        );
        return validator;
    }
});
```

Then i added this to `etc/frontend/di.xml`, depending the modules you installed, you may have different `LayoutProcessorProvider`, or you may have to use `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`, see the link i mention at the bottom for more details, here i have a checkout module to modify my checkout flow called `MyVendor\MyCheckoutModule` so i have this:

```
<type name="MyVendor\MyCheckoutModule\Model\Layout\LayoutProcessorProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="processors" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="additional-billing-address-validation" xsi:type="string">MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor\Billing\Addtional\Validation</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Then i added this `Validation.php` file

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor\Billing\Additional;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface;

class Validation implements LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['paymentMethod']['children']['billingAddress']
            ['children']['region_id']['validation']['custom-rule'] = 1;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Clear caches and refresh, the validation is now working with my select input in the billing address form.

Note that the structure could be different in `$jsLayout`, as i'm having a module to modify the checkout process so my structure is not the same with stock magento 2 layout.

Big thanks to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209042/add-rule-to-rules-js-magento2/213630#213630 for leading me in the right direction